# Directory names are not changed in for loop

Tags: python, replace, diacritics, listdir

I'm trying to recursively rename all subdirectories and files in a directory, specifically to get rid of German umlaut and replace them with their "safe" counterparts (i.e. replacing 'ü' with 'ue').

For the renaming, I found the following code

```
def remove_umlaut(string):
    """
    Removes umlauts from strings and replaces them with the letter+e convention
    :param string: string to remove umlauts from
    :return: unumlauted string
    """
    u = 'ü'.encode()
    U = 'Ü'.encode()
    a = 'ä'.encode()
    A = 'Ä'.encode()
    o = 'ö'.encode()
    O = 'Ö'.encode()
    string = string.encode()
    string = string.replace(u, b'ue')
    string = string.replace(U, b'Ue')
    string = string.replace(a, b'ae')
    string = string.replace(A, b'Ae')
    string = string.replace(o, b'oe')
    string = string.replace(O, b'Oe')
    string = string.decode('utf-8')
    return string
```

And that works when tested alone. My recursive renaming function looks like this:

```
def renameInvalid(root):
    for f in os.listdir():
        old = f 
        f = remove_umlaut(f)
        if old != f:                              
            os.rename(old,f)                
            print("renamed " + old + " to " + f )
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            os.chdir(f)
            renameInvalid(".")
            os.chdir("..")
```

When I test this in an interpreter, the issue seems to be that when iterating through os.listdir(), the strings cannot be changed. Neither with above funciton nor with regex.

Tested this on Mac and Windows.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: What do you get as output, in the case where you run it in an interpreter? What was the result of your debugging attempts?

Comment: The strings all stay the same. The print statement in renameInvalid always prints two identical strings. The same happens when I do the steps in an interpreter. I also inserted print statements in the remove_umlaut function and at no point does the string change.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "tested alone", as opposed to "in an interpreter"?

Comment: Oh I see how that's confusing. In an interpreter, it works if I use "remove_umlaut" on any string that I input. But when I try to iterate through os.listdir() in an interpreter and apply the function inside of that for-loop, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Note `string` is a bad variable name is it will hide the built in `string` package

Comment: Print the `repr()` of your strings, rather than the strings themselves, to see *exactly* what characters they contain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path

def remove_umlaut(string_with_umlaut: str) -> str:
    """
    Removes umlauts from strings and replaces them with the letter+e convention
    :param string_with_umlaut: string to remove umlauts from
    :return: unumlauted string
    """
    umlaut_alternatives = {
         'ü': 'ue',
         'Ü': 'Ue',
         'ä': 'ae',
         #... etc,
    }
    string_without_umlaut = string_with_umlaut
    for umlaut, no_umlaut in umlaut_alternatives.items():
        string_without_umlaut = string_without_umlaut.replace(umlaut, no_umlaut)
    return string_without_umlaut

def rename_invalid(root: str):

    for file in Path(root).glob("**/*"):
        file_new = remove_umlaut(file.name)
        if file_new != file.name:
            print(f"Rename {file.name} to {file_new}")
            file.rename(file.parent / file_new)
```

Comment: Does this work for you? On my end, the same behavior happens. If I insert the statement `print(string_without_umlaut)` before the return-statement, it will print a bunch of unchanged names. I'm thinking that maybe my problem doesn't have to do with coding, but that there's some other issue.

Comment: Note that here again, it's only when called withint the for-loop that it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, not sure if the directory structure would remain intact after this.

Comment: regarding the folder structure, I'd change `file.rename(file_new)` to `file.rename(file.parent / file_new)`. With regard to your other problem, I would suggest copying one of the umlauted characters directly out of your print statement, and pasting it in the dictionary and see if it now works on that character as a test. Maybe their are multiple characters that look the same but have different unicode values?

Comment: For example making the `ü` with https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm instead of http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fc/index.htm perhaps?

Comment: This is likely the correct way to the solution. It has to do with the way those characters are represented within directories, I think.

Comment: For example using the combining diacritic `'ü'.encode()` gives me `b'u\xcc\x88'` whereas `'ü'.encode()` gives me `b'\xc3\xbc'`

Comment: This is the solution! "Ö" in decomposed form is `O\xcc\x88` (found out by printing the encoded dir names) and that's what I need to use in my dictionary. Oddly enough, my python3 interpreter give `O\xc2\xa8` as its encoded, decomposed form.  Why is it different? Encodings really aren't my thing, I'm afraid.

Comment: There is a unicode character for Ö, and then there is the combining diacritic umlaut I linked to early which can be combined with an ordinary O character. These will encode differently (just like the u examples I gave. Try copying them out of the comment and encoding them for example.

Comment: I understood as much, but then I even got two different encodings for the decomposed form. Turns out, there are two different `¨` characters in Unicode, making my situation even more complicated. But now I understood it all and got my code to work on both of my machines. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Dan in the comments I figured it out.

The letters with Umlaut can be represented in two ways in UTF-8, precomposed and decomposed. The former represents them as one character while the latter represents them as their "normal" character plus the character `¨`.

My script above worked for the precomposed form but when reading from directories in Mac, they are given in decomposed form. If you encounter the same problem, here is the same code as above (even if it could be A LOT tidier) but compatible with decomposed umlaut-chars:

```
def remove_umlaut(name):
    """
    Removes umlauts from names and replaces them with the letter+e convention
    :param name: name to remove umlauts from
    :return: unumlauted name
    """
    u = b'u\xcc\x88'
    U = b'U\xcc\x88'
    a = b'a\xcc\x88'
    A = b'A\xcc\x88'
    o = b'o\xcc\x88'
    O = b'O\xcc\x88'
    ampersand = b'&'
    name = name.encode('utf8')
    name = name.replace(u, b'ue')
    name = name.replace(U, b'Ue')
    name = name.replace(a, b'ae')
    name = name.replace(A, b'Ae')
    name = name.replace(o, b'oe')
    name = name.replace(O, b'Oe')
    name = name.replace(ampersand, b'und')
    name = name.decode('utf8')
    return name

def renameInvalid(root):
    for f in os.listdir(root):
        old = f 
        f = remove_umlaut(f)
        if old != f:                              
            os.rename(old,f)                
            print("renamed " + old + " to " + f )
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            os.chdir(f)
            renameInvalid(".")
            os.chdir("..")
```